# Event handler for a web3 app

Tags: web3js, contract-development, dapp-development, events

Hey I am having trouble adding an event handlers from this tutorial I been practicing on. Heres the link to the tutorial https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/the-ultimate-ethereum-dapp-tutorial
The tutorial is outdated, so I have updated the code to reflect that.

Here is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Election {
    // Read/write candidate
    string public candidate;

    // Constructor
    constructor () public {
        addCandidate("Candidate 1");
        addCandidate("Candidate 2");
    }

    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }


    mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;

    // Store Candidates Count
    uint public candidatesCount;

    function addCandidate(string memory _name) private {
        candidatesCount ++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
    }

     // Store accounts that have voted
    mapping(address => bool) public voters;

    event voted(uint _candidateId);


    function vote (uint _candidateId) public {

        //I can make motification to allow for a database


        // require that they haven't voted before
        require(!voters[msg.sender]);

        // require a valid candidate
        require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidatesCount);

        // record that voter has voted
        voters[msg.sender] = true;

        // update candidate vote Count
        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount ++;

        voted(_candidateId);
    }


}
```

Here is the app's js:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: '0x0',

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
      web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
      // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
      web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
    }
    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON("Election.json", function(election) {
      // Instantiate a new truffle contract from the artifact
      App.contracts.Election = TruffleContract(election);
      // Connect provider to interact with contract
      App.contracts.Election.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

      return App.render();
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var electionInstance;
    var loader = $("#loader");
    var content = $("#content");

    loader.show();
    content.hide();

    // Load account data
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $("#accountAddress").html("Your Account: " + account);
      }
    });

    // Load contract data
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      electionInstance = instance;
      return electionInstance.candidatesCount();
    }).then(function(candidatesCount) {
      var candidatesResults = $("#candidatesResults");
      candidatesResults.empty();


      var candidatesSelect = $('#candidatesSelect');
      candidatesSelect.empty();

      for (var i = 1; i <= candidatesCount; i++) {
        electionInstance.candidates(i).then(function(candidate) {
          var id = candidate[0];
          var name = candidate[1];
          var voteCount = candidate[2];

          // Render candidate Result
          var candidateTemplate = "<tr><th>" + id + "</th><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + voteCount + "</td></tr>"
          candidatesResults.append(candidateTemplate);

          // Render candidate ballot option
          var candidateOption = "<option value='" + id + "' >" + name + "</ option>"
          candidatesSelect.append(candidateOption);
        });
      }
      return electionInstance.voters(App.account);
  }).then(function(hasVoted) {
    // Do not allow a user to vote
    if(hasVoted) {
      $('form').hide();
    }

      loader.hide();
      content.show();
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    });
  },

  castVote: function() {
    var candidateId = $('#candidatesSelect').val();
    App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.vote(candidateId, { from: App.account });
    }).then(function(result) {
      // Wait for votes to update
      $("#content").hide();
      $("#loader").show();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

The tutorial wants to add an event listener function right before render:function

```
listenForEvents: function() {
  App.contracts.Election.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    instance.votedEvent({}, {
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: 'latest'
    }).watch(function(error, event) {
      console.log("event triggered", event)
      // Reload when a new vote is recorded
      App.render();
    });
  });
}
```

And a function call before return App.render()

```
App.listenForEvents();
```

Once I run the server, it isn't loading fully and I noticed that this problem is coming from adding code before App.render()

What should I do?

Comment: Did you get an error message? Can you track down where the server/page is getting stuck?

Comment: No error message, the contract migrate it just doesnt load fully and doesnt allow me to vote. If I take out anything that has to do with the event handler, it works. It just doesnt reload after a event happens